# How to inject prop types into component that is wrapped by hoc

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, higher-order-components

I have a `HOC` like this

```
import React, {useEffect, useMemo, useState} from 'react'

interface WindowSize {
    width: number,
    height: number
}

export function WithWindowSize <T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
    return function WithComponent(props: T) {
        const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({} as WindowSize)

        useEffect(() => {
            ...
        }, [])


        return <Component
            {...props}
            windowSize={windowSize}/>
    }
}

export default WithWindowSize;
```

Now I want to use this `HOC`.

```
interface FooProps {
    headline: string,
    value: string | number,
}

const Foo = ({headline, value, windowSize}: FoooProps & WindowSize) => {
    return ...
}

export default WithWindowSize(Foo);
```

This gives me

> Property 'windowSize' does not exist on type 'FooProps & WindowSize'.

How would I inject the prop type `WindowSize` into `Foo`? I would think the best way is to do it in the `HOC`, so that I do not have to do it every time I wrap something with `WithWindowSize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just include the `windowSize` as an optional property in the `FooProps` interface, because there is no way for `Foo` (or any other component) to know that it is going to be used within a HOC

```
interface WindowSize {
    width: number,
    height: number
}

interface FooProps {
    headline: string,
    value: string | number,
    windowSize?: WindowSize
}

const Foo = ({headline, value, windowSize}: FooProps) => {
    return ...
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this in the `HOC`?

Comment: I don't think so. How would components know that they're being used within a HOC